# Error parsing the json representation Can not deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to map a `JSON` string to a java object and keep getting this error:

```
Error parsing the json representation Can not deserialize instance of com.mypackage.MyType out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3d9b7aeb; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I'm pretty sure this is a `JSON` syntax problem but nothing I try works. This is the `Java` code (I'm omitting the `Exception` handling for simplicity):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
BackupResource backup = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), BackupResource.class);
```

Here is my JSON string:

```
{
    "resources" : [ "resource1" , "resource2" ],
    "files" : [ "file1" , "file2" ],
    "htmls" : [ "html1" , "html2" ]    
}
```

I tried adding `[` and `]` around this string, and several other options suggested around here but nothing works. Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

EDIT: the Java class I need to map the JSON to:

```
 public class BackupResources {
    private List resources;
    private List files;
    private List htmls;

    public SystemBackupResources() {
    }

    // getters / setters....
}
```

EDIT 2: I had a mismatch between fields in the class and parts of the json. The java filed name was `htmlFiles` but the json was `htmlfiles` (no cap.) This is a string that works:

```
"{\"services\" : [ \"service1\" , \"service2\" ],   \"oFiles\" : [ \"ofile1\" , \"ofile2\" ], \"htmlFiles\" : [ \"htmlfile1\" , \"htmlfile2\" ] }"
```

but this doesn't:

```
{
    "services" : [ "service1" , "service2" ],
    "oFiles" : [ "ofile1" , "ofile2" ],
    "htmlFiles" : [ "htmlfile1" , "htmlfile2" ]    
}
```

Anyone sees the difference?

Comment: Please post your `BackupResource` class code to which you are mapping this JSON.

Comment: @SachinGupta I added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please run it again with the Java class you have provided, along with the JSON you are showing us. The exception you are showing us doesn't match this scenario. I would actually go on to say that there should be no exception at all, besides the fact that you have a bad constructor in your example. I'm guessing that's just a typo.

Comment: @peeskillet looks like there was a typo. I edited the question (EDIT 2) with the details. But something is still wrong there. Do you see it?

Comment: The one you said that doesn't work, put it in a file (exactly copy and pasted from above), and do `readValue(new File(..), BackupResource.class)`. And fix the field names in the class to match the JSON properties, and see what happens. See what happens. The only difference I see between the two is that one is String, with properly escaped `"`s and one is not escaped.

Comment: The issue was type stetting in the class I'm mapping, BackupResources. Once I set the List variables to List<String> it started working. Picky API... and bad error message...